# Why does emacs inferior eclipse backtrack only two times?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel, eclipse-clp

example:

```
[eclipse 6]: X=1;X=2;X=3.

X = 1
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ? ;    <-- this ; results in the end of the query

X = 2
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more) ?     (no chance to enter anything before the following prompt appears)

[eclipse 7]:
```

Comment: Sorry, the query doesn't show up.   The query is "X=1; X=2; X=3."

Comment: A guess: Your system assumes that you have a tty.  So simply entering `;` is sufficient.  But you entered `;` `newline` and this newline is taken as response for the next answer. You need to tell your system somehow that you are using a "dumb" terminal.

Comment: Are you using the ECLiPSe Emacs mode? You can get it at http://eclipseclp.org/Distribution/pub/eclipse_emacs.tgz

Comment: Sure, the inferior eclipse runs in eclipse mode.

Comment: Thank you false. What system and how i tell using dumb terminal, eclipse or emacs?

Comment: My advice would be to use **tkeclipse** to run and debug your code, even if you edit your sources with emacs.

Comment: But i really like to work in emacs.   A workaround is to enter several ';'  plus RET for multiple backtracks.   Wish eclipse developers could correct this problem.  Other prologs like swi, xsb and ciao all work well in emacs dumb terminals.

Comment: It used to work until a change in the inferior mode two years ago that aimed to make it more comint-compatible. A fix is in the works...

Comment: An updated version of the ECLiPSe/Emacs mode, with fixes by @twinterer, is now at http://eclipseclp.org/Distribution/pub/eclipse_emacs.tgz

Comment: Thank you jschimpf. It's ok now after eclipse.el updated:)